# Resize quad_tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, quadtree

Change the size of the matrix to 2<sup>m</sup> × 2<sup>m</sup> . This is done as
follows. If m ≥ n, replace each pixel of the original image by a 2<sup>m-n</sup> × 2<sup>m-n</sup> matrix
with all values equal to the original pixel. If m < n, divide the matrix into 2<sup>m</sup> × 2<sup>m</sup>
submatrices, each of size 2<sup>n-m</sup> × 2<sup>n-m</sup> , and replace each submatrix by a pixel whose
value occurs more often in the submatrix. If equal, choose 1.

> How to resize region quadtree of height n with height m. QUADTREE is defined as follows: 
>  An image is considered to be a 2n × 2n matrix, each of whose entries is 0 (white) or 1 (black). Each entry is called a pixel. Instead of storing the whole matrix, different data structures are used to reduce the size. The quad-tree is one such.
> A quad-tree is a rooted tree in which every node has either 0 or 4 children. Every node in the tree corresponds to some sub-matrix of the whole matrix, with size 2i × 2i for some 0 ≤ i ≤ n. The root node is the entire matrix. If all entries in a sub-matrix corresponding to a node are equal, the node is a leaf node, and it stores the value of the pixels in the sub-matrix. If there are distinct entries in the sub-matrix, divide it into 4 sub-matrices of size 2i-1 × 2i-1 , called top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left, and recursively construct the sub-trees corresponding to the 4 sub-matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented two solutions, first is for QuadTree case, second for 2D vector (array) case (my second solution was actually my first, I implemented it by mistake, forgot to notice that we need specifically QuadTree structure, but still I leave second one if it will help someone).

**First solution** using QuadTree structure.

Quad tree is implemented as QuadTree template structure that can store any data type `T`, by default it stores binary image data as `size_t` type (0/1, black/white). There are functions `CreateQT` for creating and filling quad tree of given height, `TraverseQT` a function that traverses all tree nodes and applies given callback to each of leaf nodes, `ResizeQT` that actually solves given task - resizes quad tree from current height `n` to new height `m`, `DumpQT` function that dumps quad tree to string for possibility of outputting it to console.

`main()` function just creates input tree of height `n` with `CreateQT` by filling it with random binary data by `rand() % 2` calls, then it outputs original image to console by `DumpQT` call, then resizes from height `n` to height `m` by calling `ResizeQT`, and outputs final resized image to console using `DumpQT`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVdZb@M2EH73r5i6aCCtZcVJ9sl2VKDHolsUWGSj7kvqDWiJtolIlJainKSGf3t2eEimnDhJA9QGdAzn/GY4QyVlOUwywpcPDz8ynmR1SmGaVDLN2Dzq7UhrmshCuJRasozJe5fEikoKSnKXlpPSfSXZshBMrjo8RAjSUZTTvBAdCipmfOlSFjVPJCs4yaJeXeEicJLTqiQJBfR/0utJmpcZkcgr70uqViGOeqipTiRc1CSNBaWw6QH@FEdKFxBDSiS5lhNNrdi/9FrCirLlSno@JAWvpJVQP0FlLTiauxrN4GdzH0Yt@wBOYAwjo2urr/pijMA5xJ5vFo@P4bKeDxE9WgXAOBQipQLiohz@RRcy0E@fldoAfimkLHJLty96KdSqNJhTqFZE0PS6lGLahBoF8B4i9BItb7aT3vYZjIhkiaujxWsaR6jjV0yzpBexZxEywJjAA2hSM8X4Irt2BAuWZVT4Fr7DuoXH6a1L83yLEluAZ2zA9BxG/i4Pw8giaow0sNKsoi3TohDQ@MuQdTTB21TJVjJUdJSCwYDt1FrVmFY2Q4E2aOvDEE6CJipjz9aDQGxfgHZdsBRiQdZUVEqlC0ED2DcXSiXgxc2aA@uaVQy3ZoOrwuibDNsa7AJlmRWHAuw/wIQSz8G0C0Ul7J3mRtSC1r1XQvKZKhN7gBgoOqWWt3XkUjn66wS/qxpcOEeZvY3rrkcwgqMjyNWD72zxt8HRhuEgkauCsT5tNeba9COLWsIpNwVoHsDV0czzN02J2QROYOurAp240vvNxTHG941he57GDbZYVNxR1c2pSoHyId5VHrozGKDI1XqmHNlJYjv7wHiK2u9aWkmYcE3h2lo1os02gNF20gWc1LJo7ZRj5VcXYBVMGVYUeVIwyuxbl8/EqC2VT4GkBRdMuBC@LeVNokNBK9oW37bnlhtuATPI4AtN4uJSCs8M1ma@tTGTtr4NvzDqDrhGOm65AwoG50DQq110CjlXRldlt@Upof4/vP84hFe1tm5Ev9V5ebDBva5rWdsbWVwbrW3/snWjy@XPgvE/EJOr2UFQAziwMndB2@MRL1ZGzrjXwBnA3D49OU3Csq5W13OS3HgqLXhE6ON/AHN8cTbQDm2dgb0ov/wfUaJO4jgQMl5RIT0RUp6asOZ0iYHqR017yV9L1B57LatOk2erwrbH0Qy1dkknM98PnhU6fSx0hkJaxowbxnFQEOVzc8oT948RMJ3JZHXXnhrUeK6b1GkAZ9ioNmf2/l7dna5VCYKQjBxImhNlW/iN5o/58iLu9MqPkgq1m@RKFPVyBSTLoM/zPkhayerJ6pOm@vAghB46u1@6KXbmo5qMPL@SM9Ps1DRqCKZtTjpSSVGj6il6gWx99cT1q5HThFxdsA6yriSGYwbX8Qc8GeFRtkRNLF9CsdC@wOlXDrf4BQAKsSKHNclqWoUdJRoiLXUO79o5qKnjsTmgRx4P1CZQ40@H2I5GnQkffoLT7lDqxPVJMCxmko37TRjq3nZlW1boge8fjPOyyNaYNFLdBGhbB4cb9PRrHj59FkBtiN8hjwxb@iaHtvsbsfnmgITIZAUevUtoqc6RbS@gd26ltF783jCOTZbpXXi7Irol7xu1poYne7bCMHxS9d/8hhe3HFoTP/RfVorb@OHhOw)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct QuadTree {
    typedef T data_t;
    size_t height() const {
        return st[0] ? st[0]->height() + 1 : 0;
    }
    
    T data = T();
    // Sub-trees, in order Top-Left, Top-Right, Bottom-Left, Bottom-Right.
    array< shared_ptr<QuadTree>, 4 > st = {};
};

template <typename T>
static shared_ptr< QuadTree<T> > CreateQT(size_t const height, function<T()> const & filler) {
    shared_ptr< QuadTree<T> > r(new QuadTree<T>());
    if (height <= 0)
        r->data = filler();
    else
        for (size_t i = 0; i < r->st.size(); ++i)
            r->st[i] = CreateQT(height - 1, filler);
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
static void TraverseQT(QuadTree<T> const & qt, function<void(T const &)> const & visitor) {
    if (qt.height() <= 0)
        visitor(qt.data);
    else
        for (size_t i = 0; i < qt.st.size(); ++i)
            TraverseQT<T>(*qt.st[i], visitor);
}

template <typename T>
static void ResizeQT(QuadTree<T> & qt, size_t const m) {
    size_t const n = qt.height();
    if (n == m)
        return;
    if (n > 0 && m > 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < qt.st.size(); ++i)
            ResizeQT(*qt.st[i], m - 1);
    } else if (m > 0) {
        qt.st = CreateQT<T>(m, [&](){ return qt.data; })->st;
        qt.data = T();
    } else if (n > 0) {
        map<T, size_t> cnt;
        TraverseQT<T>(qt, [&](T const & v){ ++cnt[v]; });
        // Find max
        pair<T, size_t> maxv = {{}, 0};
        for (auto const & p: cnt)
            if (p.second > maxv.second)
                maxv = p;
        qt.data = maxv.first;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < qt.st.size(); ++i)
            qt.st[i].reset();
    }
    return;
}

string VecToStr(vector<string> const & a) {
    string r;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        r += a[i];
        if (i < a.size() - 1)
            r += "\n";
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
static vector<string> DumpQT(QuadTree<T> const & qt) {
    if (qt.height() <= 0)
        return {to_string(qt.data)};
    auto JoinH = [](vector<string> const & a, vector<string> const & b) {
        vector<string> r;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < min(a.size(), b.size()); ++i)
            r.push_back(a[i] + " " + b[i]);
        return r;
    };
    auto JoinV = [](vector<string> const & a, vector<string> const & b) {
        vector<string> r = a;
        r.insert(r.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
        return r;
    };
    return JoinV(
        JoinH(DumpQT(*qt.st[0]), DumpQT(*qt.st[1])),
        JoinH(DumpQT(*qt.st[2]), DumpQT(*qt.st[3]))
    );
}

int main() {
    try {
        vector< pair<size_t, size_t> > const nm = {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}};
        srand(0);
        typedef QuadTree<size_t> ImgQT;
        // Iterate through all "nm" tests
        for (size_t t = 0; t < nm.size(); ++t) {
            size_t n = nm[t].first, m = nm[t].second;
            cout << "n = " << n << ", m = " << m << endl;
            // Create/Fill input img of size 2^n with random values.
            ImgQT img = *CreateQT<ImgQT::data_t>(n, []()->size_t{ return rand() % 2; });
            cout << "Original:" << endl << VecToStr(DumpQT(img)) << endl;
            // Solve task, resize to 2^m.
            ResizeQT(img, m);
            cout << "Resized:" << endl << VecToStr(DumpQT(img)) << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (exception const & ex) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Unknown Exception!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
n = 2, m = 3
Original:
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
Resized:
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
n = 3, m = 3
Original:
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
Resized:
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
n = 4, m = 3
Original:
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
Resized:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

---

**Second solution** using 2D vector.

In the beginning of code add extra tests to `nm` array with your desired `n` and `m` values. Input image is pre-filled with small random integer values, you may change this to read some input if needed.

Each image pixel is represented as a fixed-size array of size equal to number of channels (e.g. 1 for Gray and 3 for RGB). In next code each pixel has 1 channel, just one integer, for simplicity. Number of channels is configured by `nchans` constant, change `nchans` to e.g. 3 for testing of RGB image.

Each pixel is filled with random integers, range for random integers is controlled by next expression inside code `rand() % (t <= 1 ? 10 : 3)`, modify value after modulus `%` to change range size of possible values.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VZLb9s4EL77V0y9aCHBjhIne4q8XmCLtuilWXTbk@EtGJq2afMhkFTibODfnh2KsizZlt0tsIfyoMdgnt98Q5Jm2QUVRM1fXn7hiop8ymBIrZsKfj/q7EQPjDpt6pLcccHdU13EtXWGEVmXSZLVf4mYa8PdoqFDjCHoKLdczUERyWxGKAPMIu10uHIgCVdRDM8dwOXMU/nlV0hsCBnhZmj5P@yb60N4j2AEVCvrQEn4DZ6fr/tws@nD8035/tW/N2nlK5htbeiCKIt2gxQuL@FTLu@ZAT0DL1dMWIioFtrYuA8smScwgJk28AFLAaKmcFP8fv7wR1L5d08Zm7IZFPVWyYZAI/iTr5n4UsvGoJvoKt5JMI2PjhniGLiF0fl8AUQI6CrZBcess5WmDx2V5Tis4SrF1xBxSLwwilPo9Vxcg7EOZfkO@XgQuZynDc3Ss0LPSo7dJJlxY7EUWQksQxSnTSuqc0xiiPmiWtd/qeI32BUC6R9MTUWL5Z3hc66IuO0eV0SE3iIDHbt8zxEZrjI0xPR933zScP23gkfkH3hwtYQHInJmk30n0aBILwZuwSIhgdjCNMr0Y2DBddw0qiPOA@IcEd868oDzfcD9wuQSw4qu@M/QHujBIE4PdOsxliHGci/G8lgMv0I3IfODsEmPqtTdr4L7FbrPapxZtbn3KxuvJmhW0DaG1xBhz3B84HcYXMEt3MRpq@m2wd5FuxafQVTPCC4QplbtBnH63eNuN52TZtBihq0a80mS5Xbx7Z7QVZQdKe7Q99bvIXE3@wz8S4sHHHNiV30I/ACnkYMy@b6Z1QdD69FTviPyWBNP8le289cvXSOxPsvis0yWp5m8jdhswEkaFNowGkEkkTMqnoyX9b9W2/h7SdOUbACPB/bTg@w3U53j8auqs09TmuN8U2ZbrfDAL2m4O4epcu1Tvb/tRNznh1S9wCTjsAdFTSEWHarYCsrN6SQJ6nGEj7NsxhFFnOX5OOJ0HL96PSx57Gm3mozF5MSehiC/53hdkGTdvrH6u80@pmjwUNxq8CZztTkDL8lx8wj3mjeQ3fqGnC7CbxZZeYpDCFb@nS@@zCxL/8P4FgGKW8SPztz@BnqXO3/448Tkwtnj14nPxThN224TLeNam77WiW2ZvW3hO@vWCWy2DF2UtuPl5P85vn@mM/jHjtbdl2EuNwoh6oT9mhJHFxCxNWWZ41pVwLN1HbIqp3dbxdtwb2Xr5HFBHMJxkEIZ6mKwFytJkqOuv6qV0o8KqhCvuueddjadl5d/AQ)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        vector< pair<size_t, size_t> > const nm = {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}};
        size_t const nchans = 1; // Number of channels (colors), e.g. 1 for Gray and 3 for RGB.
        typedef array<size_t, nchans> PixelT;
        srand(0);
        // Iterate through all "nm" tests
        for (size_t t = 0; t < nm.size(); ++t) {
            vector< vector<PixelT> > img;
            size_t n = nm[t].first, m = nm[t].second;
            cout << "n = " << n << ", m = " << m << endl;
            cout << "Original:" << endl;
            // Create/Fill input img of size 2^n with random values.
            // (1 << n) is same as 2^n (power of 2).
            for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << n); ++i) {
                img.resize(img.size() + 1);
                for (size_t j = 0; j < (1 << n); ++j) {
                    PixelT p = {};
                    for (size_t k = 0; k < p.size(); ++k) {
                        p[k] = rand() % (t <= 1 ? 10 : 3);
                        cout << p[k];
                        if (k < p.size() - 1)
                            cout << ",";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                    img[i].push_back(p);
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            // Solve task, resize to 2^m.
            vector< vector<PixelT> > oimg;
            if (n <= m) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << m); ++i) {
                    oimg.resize(oimg.size() + 1);
                    for (size_t j = 0; j < (1 << m); ++j) {
                        oimg[i].push_back(
                            img[i >> (m - n)][j >> (m - n)]
                        );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << m); ++i) {
                    oimg.resize(oimg.size() + 1);
                    for (size_t j = 0; j < (1 << m); ++j) {
                        // Count number of occurances
                        map<PixelT, size_t> cnt;
                        for (size_t k = (i << (n - m)); k < ((i << (n - m)) + (1 << (n - m))); ++k)
                            for (size_t l = (j << (n - m)); l < ((j << (n - m)) + (1 << (n - m))); ++l)
                                ++cnt[img[k][l]];
                        // Find max
                        pair<PixelT, size_t> maxv = {{}, 0};
                        for (auto const & p: cnt)
                            if (p.second > maxv.second)
                                maxv = p;
                        oimg[i].push_back(maxv.first);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Output results
            cout << "Resized:" << endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < oimg.size(); ++i) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < oimg[i].size(); ++j) {
                    auto const & p = oimg[i][j];
                    for (size_t k = 0; k < p.size(); ++k) {
                        cout << p[k];
                        if (k < p.size() - 1)
                            cout << ",";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (exception const & ex) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Unknown Exception!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Example output for Gray image (`nchans = 1`):

```
n = 2, m = 3
Original:
8 9 8 7 
5 7 5 5 
0 2 3 0 
2 1 7 1 
Resized:
8 8 9 9 8 8 7 7 
8 8 9 9 8 8 7 7 
5 5 7 7 5 5 5 5 
5 5 7 7 5 5 5 5 
0 0 2 2 3 3 0 0 
0 0 2 2 3 3 0 0 
2 2 1 1 7 7 1 1 
2 2 1 1 7 7 1 1 
n = 3, m = 3
Original:
5 5 7 0 6 1 5 6 
7 3 1 0 5 8 6 0 
0 7 7 7 1 7 6 7 
3 8 3 7 7 4 2 1 
8 6 9 4 9 5 8 9 
9 6 1 4 4 6 8 2 
2 4 7 6 8 2 7 3 
3 3 0 2 7 5 1 4 
Resized:
5 5 7 0 6 1 5 6 
7 3 1 0 5 8 6 0 
0 7 7 7 1 7 6 7 
3 8 3 7 7 4 2 1 
8 6 9 4 9 5 8 9 
9 6 1 4 4 6 8 2 
2 4 7 6 8 2 7 3 
3 3 0 2 7 5 1 4 
n = 4, m = 3
Original:
2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 
0 0 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 2 
1 0 2 0 1 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 1 
2 1 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 2 1 2 
1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 1 2 
2 1 0 0 1 2 1 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 
0 1 1 2 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 2 2 1 
0 0 0 2 0 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 
1 1 1 0 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 
1 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 
1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 
1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 0 
Resized:
0 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 2 1 2 
1 0 1 0 2 0 0 2 
0 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 
1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 
1 1 1 2 0 0 0 2 
0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0
```

Example output for RGB image (`nchans = 3`):

```
n = 2, m = 3
Original:
8,9,8 7,5,7 5,5,0 2,3,0 
2,1,7 1,5,5 7,0,6 1,5,6 
7,3,1 0,5,8 6,0,0 7,7,7 
1,7,6 7,3,8 3,7,7 4,2,1 
Resized:
8,9,8 8,9,8 7,5,7 7,5,7 5,5,0 5,5,0 2,3,0 2,3,0 
8,9,8 8,9,8 7,5,7 7,5,7 5,5,0 5,5,0 2,3,0 2,3,0 
2,1,7 2,1,7 1,5,5 1,5,5 7,0,6 7,0,6 1,5,6 1,5,6 
2,1,7 2,1,7 1,5,5 1,5,5 7,0,6 7,0,6 1,5,6 1,5,6 
7,3,1 7,3,1 0,5,8 0,5,8 6,0,0 6,0,0 7,7,7 7,7,7 
7,3,1 7,3,1 0,5,8 0,5,8 6,0,0 6,0,0 7,7,7 7,7,7 
1,7,6 1,7,6 7,3,8 7,3,8 3,7,7 3,7,7 4,2,1 4,2,1 
1,7,6 1,7,6 7,3,8 7,3,8 3,7,7 3,7,7 4,2,1 4,2,1 
n = 3, m = 3
Original:
8,6,9 4,9,5 8,9,9 6,1,4 4,6,8 2,2,4 7,6,8 2,7,3 
3,3,0 2,7,5 1,4,3 2,9,4 9,6,4 7,3,5 3,3,0 4,3,1 
4,5,9 0,7,6 9,6,9 7,0,3 2,4,1 2,5,1 9,7,0 0,4,8 
4,7,6 1,8,2 0,4,1 5,7,0 4,2,6 7,3,4 8,4,4 1,7,6 
6,3,0 2,7,0 7,8,3 3,9,3 1,4,1 3,2,1 4,0,9 4,1,2 
0,2,8 6,1,5 6,9,8 5,7,0 4,3,5 1,4,7 6,6,1 7,4,1 
3,9,4 6,4,9 5,7,0 2,5,0 6,0,2 3,5,7 8,7,5 1,0,7 
3,1,6 2,7,2 1,3,2 5,5,6 5,9,7 3,3,7 2,2,1 4,6,5 
Resized:
8,6,9 4,9,5 8,9,9 6,1,4 4,6,8 2,2,4 7,6,8 2,7,3 
3,3,0 2,7,5 1,4,3 2,9,4 9,6,4 7,3,5 3,3,0 4,3,1 
4,5,9 0,7,6 9,6,9 7,0,3 2,4,1 2,5,1 9,7,0 0,4,8 
4,7,6 1,8,2 0,4,1 5,7,0 4,2,6 7,3,4 8,4,4 1,7,6 
6,3,0 2,7,0 7,8,3 3,9,3 1,4,1 3,2,1 4,0,9 4,1,2 
0,2,8 6,1,5 6,9,8 5,7,0 4,3,5 1,4,7 6,6,1 7,4,1 
3,9,4 6,4,9 5,7,0 2,5,0 6,0,2 3,5,7 8,7,5 1,0,7 
3,1,6 2,7,2 1,3,2 5,5,6 5,9,7 3,3,7 2,2,1 4,6,5 
n = 4, m = 3
Original:
1,1,0 1,0,0 1,0,1 1,0,0 0,1,0 1,0,1 0,1,0 0,0,1 0,1,1 1,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,1 1,1,0 0,1,0 1,1,0 0,0,0 
0,1,0 1,1,1 1,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,0 0,0,0 1,0,0 0,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,1 0,0,1 1,1,0 0,0,1 1,0,1 
0,0,1 1,0,1 0,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 0,0,1 1,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,1 1,0,1 1,0,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 
1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,1 0,0,1 1,1,1 0,0,0 1,0,0 0,0,0 1,1,1 1,1,0 1,1,0 1,1,0 0,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,1 0,1,0 
0,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,1 0,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,1 0,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 0,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 0,0,1 1,1,1 1,0,0 
1,1,1 0,1,1 1,1,0 0,0,1 1,0,1 1,0,0 0,1,1 0,1,1 0,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,0 0,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,0 
0,1,0 1,0,0 1,1,1 0,1,1 0,0,0 0,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,1 1,0,1 0,0,1 1,0,0 0,1,1 1,1,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 
0,1,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 1,0,0 1,1,0 0,0,1 1,1,1 1,1,0 1,1,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 1,1,1 1,0,1 
1,0,0 0,0,1 1,0,1 0,1,1 1,1,1 1,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,1 0,1,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 1,0,1 1,0,1 1,0,0 1,1,0 0,1,1 
0,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 0,1,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,1 1,0,0 1,0,1 
0,1,1 0,1,0 0,0,0 1,0,1 1,0,1 1,0,0 1,0,0 0,1,1 1,1,1 1,0,0 1,0,1 0,0,0 1,0,0 0,1,1 0,1,0 0,1,0 
0,1,0 0,0,0 1,0,1 0,0,1 0,1,0 1,0,0 1,0,1 0,0,0 1,1,1 1,1,0 0,0,0 0,0,1 0,0,1 1,1,0 1,1,1 0,1,1 
1,1,1 1,0,0 0,1,0 1,0,0 0,0,1 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,0 1,1,1 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,1 1,0,0 
1,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,1,1 1,0,1 0,1,0 1,1,1 0,0,1 0,0,0 0,0,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 1,1,0 
1,0,1 1,1,1 0,1,0 1,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,1 1,0,0 0,0,1 0,0,1 1,1,0 0,1,0 1,0,1 0,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,0 
0,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,1 1,1,0 1,0,1 1,1,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 1,1,1 0,1,1 0,0,0 0,0,0 0,0,0 
Resized:
0,1,0 1,0,1 0,1,0 0,0,1 1,1,0 0,1,1 1,1,0 0,0,0 
1,1,1 0,0,1 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,0,1 1,1,0 1,0,0 0,1,0 
0,1,1 0,0,1 1,0,1 0,1,1 0,0,1 1,1,1 0,0,1 0,0,0 
0,1,0 0,1,0 0,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,1 0,0,1 0,1,0 1,1,1 
0,0,1 0,1,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,1 0,0,0 0,1,1 
0,1,0 1,0,1 1,0,0 0,0,0 1,1,1 0,0,0 0,0,1 0,1,0 
1,1,1 0,1,0 0,0,1 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,0,0 0,0,0 1,1,0 
0,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 1,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,0 0,0,0
```

Comment: I need quadTree implementation

Comment: @String Alright, I can convert my solution to quad-tree. How do you want this quad-tree to be stored? Just the way I want, e.g. by `struct` with 4 pointers inside it to store pointers to sub-trees?

Comment: class QuadTree { <br> int p; int height; QuadTree* TR; QuadTree* TL; };

Comment: Assume it is binary image.. and quadtree(int n) { p=0; height=n;} a constructor

Comment: @String If it is a quad tree why does it have only two pointers inside? There are 4 quadrants, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right, hence should be 4 pointers for 4 sub-trees. Also why does it has only `height`, where is `width`? Or width is assumed to always be equal to height? Also what is `p`, is it a pixel value? For binary image it is either 0 or 1?

Comment: 1. 4 pointers 2. Assume, height == width 3. Yes, it is either 0 or 1.

Comment: I added how quadtree is defined in post itself.

Comment: @String Done! Just implemented same algorithm as before but using `QuadTree` structure, see my updated answer.